# Material UI migration to V5: MUI component received wrong theme color through SX

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I just migrated my material UI version from 4 to 5. Everything went well, but now I have this strange bug:

Everywhere else on the app the theme colors are displayed correctly, but this Tabs component displays default MUI theme colors. I have changed the color of this through the 'sx' property. Perhaps I did something wrong here?

Someone knows what could cause this issue?

**The green color is the normal secondary color, and everywhere on the app it displays it correctly, but the Tab component uses purple instead (the MUI default theme secondary color)**
[image]

**Tabs logic I use: I pass 'secondary-light to sx prop**

```
<TabContext value={value}>
        <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: "divider" }}>
          <TabList onChange={handleChange} aria-label="lab API tabs example">
            {blocks.map((block) => (
              <Tab
                sx={{
                  boxShadow: "0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
                  "&.MuiTab-root": {
                    color: 'secondary.light',
                  },
                }}
                label={block.label}
                value={block.key}
              />
            ))}
          </TabList>
        </Box>
        {blocks.map((block) => (
          <TabPanel value={block.key}>
            <TabsPanelContent displayedBlock={block} step={step} />
          </TabPanel>
        ))}
      </TabContext>
```

**App.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router";

import AppProviders from "./AppProviders";
import AppInitializer from "./AppInitializer";
import AppLayout from "./AppLayout";
import ComplianceErrorBoundary from "components/errorBoundary/ComplianceErrorBoundary";
import { MuiThemeProvider as ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core";
import { myfaro } from "@myfaro/themes-mui";

import { ErrorBoundary } from "components";
import { InvestorProfileWizard } from "components/wizard/customWizards/investorProfileWizard/InvestorProfileWizard";
import { ComplianceWizard } from "components/wizard/customWizards/complianceWizard/ComplianceWizard";
import { StepProvider } from "components/wizard/providers/StepProvider";

import { Initiation } from "components/wizard/customWizards/complianceWizard/Initiation";
import { appsignal } from "helpers/appsignalInstance";
import AppsignalErrorBoundary from "components/errorBoundary/AppsignalErrorBoundary";
import { WizardRoutes } from "components/wizard/routes/WizardRoutes";

const baseName =
  window.location.href.indexOf("localhost") > -1 ? "/" : "/web-app";

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={myfaro}>
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <AppProviders>
          <AppInitializer>
            <AppLayout>
              <Router basename={baseName}>
                <Switch>
                  <Route path="/mifid_files/:mifid_file_uid">
                    <StepProvider mainWizardName="investorProfile">
                      <InvestorProfileWizard />
                    </StepProvider>
                  </Route>
                  <Route exact path="/compliance/:case_file_uid/init">
                    <Initiation />
                  </Route>
                  <Route path="/compliance/:case_file_uid/:mifid_file_uid">
                    <AppsignalErrorBoundary
                      namespace='compliance'
                      instance={appsignal}
                      fallback={(error) => (
                        <ComplianceErrorBoundary error={error} />
                      )}
                    >
                      <StepProvider mainWizardName="compliance">
                        <ComplianceWizard />
                      </StepProvider>
                    </AppsignalErrorBoundary>
                  </Route>
                  {/* TODO: eventually, we should put the compliance wizards in here */}
                  <WizardRoutes />
                </Switch>
              </Router>
            </AppLayout>
          </AppInitializer>
        </AppProviders>
      </ErrorBoundary>
    </ThemeProvider>

  );
}

export default App;
```

**My custom theme**

```
import { createTheme, responsiveFontSizes } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import purple from '@material-ui/core/colors/purple';
import green from '@material-ui/core/colors/green';
import yellow from '@material-ui/core/colors/yellow';
import red from '@material-ui/core/colors/red';
import globalTheme from './general';
import overrides from './overrides';

const theme = createTheme(globalTheme, {
  palette: {
    primary: {
      ...purple,
      main: '#0d9ee3',
      light: '#48BDF5',
      dark: '#0A7BB1',
      100: '#E4EEFA',
    },
    secondary: {
      ...green,
      main: green[500],
      light: green[300],
      dark: green[700],
    },
    text: {
      primary: '#212529',
      secondary: 'rgba(33, 37, 41, 0.8)',
    },
    background: {
      paper: '#fff',
      default: '#fafafa',
    },
    results: {
      bad: {
        main: red[500],
        light: red[200],
        dark: red[800],
      },
      caution: {
        main: yellow[500],
        light: yellow[200],
        dark: yellow[800],
      },
      good: {
        main: green[500],
        light: green[200],
        dark: green[800],
      },
    },
  },
  typography: {
    button: {
      // fontStyle: "italic"
      fontWeight: 500,
      textTransform: 'none',
    },
  },
});

export default responsiveFontSizes(overrides(theme));
```

EDIT:react devtools inspect

[image]

EDIT 2: first parent with theme:

[image]

Comment: This can sometimes happen if you for some reason have more than 1 theme provider. Can you inspect the component with react dev tools and check what theme props it is using?

Comment: I added a screenshot. I'm not sure I'm looking at the right thing though, let me know if you meant something different

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right! Now we must figure out why the theme is null. Can you go up the React tree in dev tools and see if you can find `ThemeProvider` somewhere as a parent component?

Comment: Found the themeprovider at the very top, it has the green as secondary color. screenshot posted

Comment: Besides that one, no other themeproviders in the tree

Comment: Interesting. But clearly _something_ breaks it. Can you go back to the Tab component and inspect parents until you get a theme that isn't null?

Comment: The first one I came across was the component 'Tabs' (see screenshot). It's the child of TabsList

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240570/discussion-between-summer-and-tilly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We didn't quite finish [our discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240570/discussion-between-summer-and-tilly), but I'm just going to list the probable suspects for anybody who runs into the same issue.

Most of the time, conflicting themes like this are caused by multiple instances of `<ThemeProvider />` or its styling engine, whether that's JSS, emotion or styled-components. Either you have incorrectly nested themes, or you have imported a component that ships its own Mui palette... such as components from `material-ui/core` used inside `@mui/material` components.

If you've fully removed the legacy version from your app and are totally sure you're not using any offending components, your best course of action is to start checking for the Theme props in React dev tools, starting from the mismatched component and working your way up the tree. The offender has to be there somewhere.

Comment: What could be the reason that useTheme does return the right theme, but the components style is still the default MUI theme?

Comment: I did change the import of the themeprovider to @mui/material/styles. So now all color is the same, however, it's all default theme now.

So the right theme still gets passed when I access it using useTheme() hook, but when I render a component with a theme color, it still shows the default MUI theme colors.

Comment: and oh yeah, I tested it in the first component right after ThemeProvider and it returned the MUI colors there as well, so I must be doing something wrong with my setup, but then I don't get why the useTheme hook does return the same colors. aaargh

Comment: @tilly Might be a conflict with the styles engine. Sharing the code would help. :D I'm busy all day today and don't really have time to experiment in a sandbox.